# Xamarin Android C# SQLite Parameter Query

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to return data based on a parameter in Xamarin Android C#. I've got the below code working when pulling all data back, however I need to use a SQLite WHERE query to return specific data.

I need to use the value from an AutoCompleteTextView field for the parameter..

```
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        sqliteDB = db.WritableDatabase;

        container = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.container);

        var btnEmergencyServices = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEmergencyServices);
        btnEmergencyServices.Click += btnEmergencyServices_onClick;
    }
```

---

```
private void EmergencyServicesData()
    {
        ICursor selectData = sqliteDB.RawQuery("select POLICE, FIRE, MEDICAL from EmergencyServices WHERE COUNTRY = @Country", new string[] { });
        if (selectData.Count > 0)
        {
            selectData.MoveToFirst();
            do
            {
                EmergencyServices emergencyServices = new EmergencyServices();
                emergencyServices.POLICE = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("POLICE"));
                emergencyServices.FIRE = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("FIRE"));
                emergencyServices.MEDICAL = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("MEDICAL"));
                EmergencyServices.Add(emergencyServices);
            }
            while (selectData.MoveToNext());
            selectData.Close();
        }
        foreach (var item in EmergencyServices)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EmergencyServices, null);
            TextView txtPolice = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPolice);
            TextView txtFire = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFire);
            TextView txtMedical = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtMedical);
            txtPolice.Text = item.POLICE;
            txtFire.Text = item.FIRE;
            txtMedical.Text = item.MEDICAL;
            container.AddView(addView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I use a parameter with my query?

Comment: I cannot really make heads or tails of if this is the case, but if you're using SqliteCommand anywhere use the Parameters collection property. What exactly is DBHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I use a parameter with my query?

Assuming you are using one of the Sqlite net package variants (I use `sqlite-net-pcl`), you create a string array with the parameters **in the order** that they are to be substituted within the SQL query (marked via `?`).

In this example, yanked straight from one of my apps, is passing two parameters in the method, a `string` and a `bool`.

One needs to convert the string representation of `0` or `1` as booleans are stored as integers in SQLite.

The other gets whitespace trimmed and I add the SQL string wildcard `%` to beginning and end of string.

I create a string array with those two variables and my SQL statement contains two `?` that will be replaced with those parameters in the left-2-right order that they are found in the SQL query statement.

#### Example

```
public async Task<IList<Package>> DbGetSearchedPackagesAsync(string constraint, bool isUserApp = true)
{
    var param1 = Convert.ToInt32(isUserApp).ToString();
    var param2 = $"%{constraint.Trim()}%";
    var packages = await conn.QueryAsync<Package>("SELECT * FROM Package WHERE UserApp = ? AND Name LIKE ? ORDER BY Name COLLATE NOCASE ASC;", new string[2] { param1, param2 });
    return packages;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, I'm assuming I can take the value from my AutoCompleteTextView as my parameter easily enough?

Comment: @WHoward Absolutely, my example is from an `SearchView` (`Xamarin.Android`-based) and passes the user's search entry to this method to filter the `RecyclerView`, in your case you would take the returned `IList` and present that to the user as dropdown list under the auto-complete entry (assuming that is your end goal).

Comment: Kinda, the user will enter the country of choice and based on that the data associated with that will be returned/displayed to the user. Thanks again