# Get Data From Sqlite Database with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

When I created an app with Xamarin and sqlite. I run an statement, but it show me this sentence in emulator screen: System.Linq.Enumerable + SelectEnumerableIterator`2[AppUI.Entries, System.String]

Here is my Entries class:

```
public class Entries
{
    public Entries()
    {

    }

    public Entries(string word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public Entries(string word, string wordtype, string definition)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.type = wordtype;
        this.defn = definition;
    }   
    public string word
    { get; set; }

    public string type
    { get; set; }

    public string sdex { get; set; }
    public int wlen { get; set; }

    public string defn
    { get; set; }
```

Here is DatabaseManager class. function GetDef() is the statement that i recommended.

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    SQLiteConnection dbConnection;
    public DatabaseManager()
    {
        dbConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
    }


    public string GetDef(string w)
    {
        return dbConnection.Table<Entries>().Where(x => x.word == w).Select(x => x.defn).ToString();
    }


}
```

I don't know why it happened? Please help. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the query and Linq is returning an `IEnumerable` (ie. zero or more `Entries` objects).

```
dbConnection.Table<Entries>().Where(x => x.word == w)
```

This part of the Linq projection is assuming it only has one `Entries` object:

```
.Select(x => x.defn).ToString();
```

So use either `First` to take the first record from the enumeration (or return `null` with the `FirstOrDefault` if no records exist ):

```
return dbConnection.Table<Entries>()
          .Where(x => x.word == w)
          .FirstOrDefault()?
          .defn;
```

Comment: thank you so much. I try it now. But it gives another error: 'Entries" does not contain a definition for "Select" and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first arguement of type 'Entries' could not be found (are you missing  a using directive  or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TanVuBoyGib I updated the answer to remove the final `Select`.  `.FirstOrDefault()?.defn;`

Comment: thank you so much again. you helped me a lot. I will try it now.

Comment: i tried. this time it show nothing on emulator screen. i think this: dbConnection.Table<Entries>().Where(x => x.word == w) return zero like you said

Comment: my idea for this statement is like this: select defn from Entries where word = w

Comment: Assuming you have records in that table... You can use SQL query, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892352/4984832